# calculating confidence while doing classification

Tags: statistics, machine-learning, nlp, probability

I am using a Naive Bayes algorithm to predict movie ratings as positive or negative. I have been able to rate movies with 81% accuracy. I am, however, trying to assign a 'confidence level' for each of the ratings as well.

I am trying to identify how I can tell the user something like "we think that the review is positive **with 80% confidence**". Can someone help me understand how I can calculate a confidence level to our classification result?

Comment: Could you maybe share a bit of your implementation? It's hard to tell how you implemented Naive Bayes: as a probabilistic classifier (Which does what you want out of the box) or as a linear model (which is a tad faster).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can report the probability P(*y*|**x**) that Naive Bayes calculates. (But note that Naive Bayes isn't a very good probability model, even if it's not too bad a classifier.)

Comment: As Naive Bayes actually calculates very "small" values, wouldn't it be better to report (for binary classification with "positive" result) P(positive|x)/(P(positive|x)+P(negative|x)) as the "score" for the user?

Comment: @lejlot P(pos|x) + P(neg|x) = 1, so I don't see what this changes.

Comment: This only applies to probability, not for values stored by typical implementation of NB (which are commonly unnormalized, right?)

Comment: @lejlot: depends on the OP's implementation, but if you call the values from NB P(y|x), then that's suggesting they're probabilities :)

Comment: p(positive|x) is the normalised, posterior probability of class membership. The likelihood p(x|positive) is the thing that's very small. Larsmans is absolutely correct